# How can I filter Windows 10/11 notifications based on string/regex?

Tags: windows-10, regex, notifications

I'm looking for a way to filter Windows 10/11 notifications based on their content, be it string match or even regex.

My current use case is that I'm in a Discord server which has a "firehose" channel which sends out a ton of messages for which I get notifications. Discord itself has no way to filter notifications based on their content, and the way this Discord server is setup it's either all or nothing. I care about only messages containing a few specific strings. Everything I don't care about and want to filter them out.

Ultimately, I'm looking for something that can pattern match my string/regex to display(or hide/dismiss) notifications. This can be useful not just for Discord but other apps too.

Comment: Never heard about anything like that on Windows, although it looks possible: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/notification-listener#remove-a-specific-notification I know a way to do it on Android, however, if that satisfies you. You could ask a more software oriented question here instead and ping me in comment, then I'll answer: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/unanswered

Comment: @Destroy666, yes I'm looking for something along the lines of Android's "FilterBox Notification Manager", but obviously for Windows.